# Поиск равновесия или вроде того на Си

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, математика, ряды

помогите пожалуйста с таким заданием: есть последовательность чисел от 1 до числа которое введёт пользователь, начинаем складывать числа слева направо, нужно найти момент когда нужно закончить сложение слева и начать складывать с другой стороны, нужно что бы разность между сторонами была минимальна(типо равновесия у предмета со смещённым центром тяжести) например 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 - складываем слева получается 15, справа 13, минимальная разность в таком диапазоне - 2.
вот что сделано на данный момент: заполнение массива, цикл для сложения левой части, с правой вроде бы косяк.

```
static int start = 1, end, left_sum, right_sum, diff;

int main(void)
{
    system("chcp 1251 > nul");
    printf("Введите конечное число: ");
    scanf("%d", &end);

    int *arr = (int*)malloc(end * sizeof(int));

    fill_arr(end, arr);

    printf("Последовательность чисел в массиве: \n");
    print_arr(end, arr);

    sum_of_side(end, arr);

    //difference(left_sum, right_sum);

    //print_diff(diff);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void fill_arr(int end, int *arr)
{   
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= end; i++)
    {
        *(arr + i) = i;
    }
}

void sum_of_side(int end, int *arr)
{
    int i = 1, tmp;

    if(*(arr + i) <= end)
    {
        printf("Числа с левой стороны: \n");
        for (i; *(arr + i) <= end; i++)
        {
            tmp = *(arr + i) + *(arr + (i + 1));
            *(arr + i + 1) = tmp;
            printf("%d ", *(arr + i));
            left_sum = *(arr + i);
        }

        printf("\n Сумма чисел слева: %d \n", left_sum);
    }
    if(*(arr + end) <= end)
    {
        printf("Числа с правой стороны: \n");
        for (i = end; *(arr + (i - 1)) <= end; i--)
        {
            tmp = *(arr + i) + *(arr + (i - 1));
            *(arr + i - 1) = tmp;
            printf("%d ", *(arr + (i - 1)));
            right_sum = *(arr + (i - 1));
        }

        printf("\n Сумма чисел справа: %d \n", right_sum);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int difference(int left_sum, int right_sum)
{
    diff = left_sum - right_sum;
    return diff;
}

void print_arr(int end, int *arr)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= end; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void print_diff(int diff)
{
    printf("Разность между сторонами: %d\n", diff);
}
```

Comment: А обязательно по одному складывать? Можно же парой формул решить.

Comment: в принципе не обязательно наверное, но лучше вручную всё без библиотечных функций и всего такого)

Comment: Если в моем решении вас смущает `sqrt` как библиотечная функция... ну, берите корень методом Ньютона - сходится обязательно и очень быстро :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Просто смотрим сумму от 1 до `k` - это

```
k(k+1)/2
```

От `k+1` до `n` -

```
(n+k+1)(n-k)/2
```

Разность между ними равна

```
n(n+1)/2 - k(k+1)
```

Нам нужно, чтоб она стала равна 0 (в идеале).

Решаем квадратное уравнение, находим

```
(sqrt(2*n*n+2*n+1)-1)/2
```

Для 7, например,

```
k = 4.82
```

Т.е. делить надо при `k = 5`.

Сами код напишете или нужно помогать? :) Можно при неточном значении не округлять, а посмотреть два варианта - какой точнее подходит...

**Update**

Вот [простенький код](http://ideone.com/V2nwrw)...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned int pivot(unsigned int n)
{
    return (sqrt(2*n*n+2*n+1)-1)/2+0.5;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(unsigned int n = 3; n <= 50; ++n)
    {
        unsigned int k = pivot(n);
        printf("%2d: k = %2d  left sum = %5d  right sum = %5d,  delte = %-3d\n",
               n,k, k*(k+1)/2,(n+k+1)*(n-k)/2, k*(k+1)/2 - (n+k+1)*(n-k)/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если нетрудно, могли бы помочь с кодом? я всё с условием самим мучаюсь, туплю что-то сейчас)

Comment: Без проблем. `k = (sqrt(2*n*n+2*n+1)-1)/2+0.5;`

Comment: чёт совсем туплю, не пойму куда это пристроить что бы всё заработало как следует, а sqrt это же библиотечная функция? можно без неё как-то? блин я с этим заданием странным чёт запутался ужас, даже правильно объяснить что нужно сложно :)

Comment: Нужно получается слева числа складывать и справа и разность между этими сторонами должна быть минимальна, то есть как я понял идёт к примеру 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 - складывается 1 и 2 получается 3 проверяем не больше ли оно последнему числу наверное, а потом когда оно становится больше складывается уже с другой стороны хз как даже что-то)) в итоге типо с одной получается 15 с другой 13 в итоге разность 2, меньше по сути не добиться уже.

Comment: Да ничего не надо по одному числу проверять...

Answer (score 1):

Благодарю за помощь, буду дальше разбираться что к чему :)
P.S Учитель сделал вот так вот:

```
int main(void)
{
    int start = 1, end, start_current = start, end_current;
    system ("chcp 1251 > nul");
    printf("Введите конечное число: ");
    scanf("%d", &end);
    end_current = end;

    while (start_current < end_current)
    {
        if (start <= end)
        {
            start_current++;
            start += start_current;
        }
        else
        {
            end_current--;
            end += end_current;
        }
    }

    printf("%d", start_current);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Объясните ему, что O(1) все же лучше чем O(N)